# Mechanics of BibLaTeX: proper connection of .bib file

Tags: biblatex, texniccenter, texstudio

Ok, I've experienced weird behavior with TeXstudio. I want to add bibliography directly to `.bib` file while using `biblatex`. People seem to do in this way. I don't want bibliography inside of the `.tex` file, but want to separately modify the `.bib` file  - this is the condition

```
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @article{JoeDoe2012,
    Author = {Joe Doe},
    Year = {2012},
    Title = {My article's title},
    Journal = {My journal's title},
    Editor = {Ben Editor},
    URL = {http://webpage.com},
  }

\end{filecontents}
```

In TeXstudio, in order to update (say after adding second item in `filecontents`), you have to delete all the files except `.tex` every time . Recompiling dozen times - no reaction, no update. Adding item directly to `.bib` file - no reaction, no update again after recompiling. During these operations it complains that another `.bib` file with project name already exists - adding entries there gives no result either. It breaks also when you just try add `.bib` file without `filecontents` directly to a `.tex` file now giving annoying error:

```
I have no clue what `\addbibresource` command is
```

Yes, after you've executed it twice with `filecontents`, same as saying I don't understand what is water while drinking Pepsi. The result is always unresolved references.

In TeXnicCenter it seems that connection occurs after you add two of these and then remove `filecontents` - now you are able to edit `.bib` file and recompiling gives you updated results.

I've always wanted to use TeXstudio due to GUI stuff but it keeps me failing over and over again.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your workflow. Generally you shouldn't use `filecontents` to manage your `.bib` file; that's only for when it's crucial that the TeX file contains the bibliography file itself. Normally you would use a GUI reference manager for the `.bib` file and every time you save that file, the next time you run `bibtex` or `biber` those changes will be reflected in your document.

Comment: A miscellaneous points: (1) Without `\usepackage{filecontents}`, you can't update what's in the environment and get it written to the created filecontents file; loading the package is therefore highly recommended. (2) You probably mean `\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}` (note the slash before jobname!): this tells `biblatex` that the bibliography file it is looking for will have the same name as the `.tex` file, but with the extension `.bib`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me the easiest way of doing this is by creating a seperate .bib file, for example you can open a new window in your editor, paste your code

```
@article{JoeDoe2012,
    Author  = {Joe Doe},
    Year    = {2012},
    Title   = {My article's title},
    Journal = {My journal's title},
    Editor  = {Ben Editor},
    URL     = {http://webpage.com},
    }
```

and save as for example `jobname.bib` (I wouldn't use backslashes in the filename, this can lead to problems when refering to it in your .tex file) in the same folder as your .tex file is in.

You said

> I have no clue what `\addbibresource` command is

This becomes apparent in the following example file, where it is used to include the bibliography that you enclosed using `\begin{filecontents}...\end{filecontents}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

This statement has a checkable source \cite{JoeDoe2012}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The `backend=bibtex` argument is used to tell biblatex to use bibtex (you could also use biber, which is often preferred) and `style=numeric` is used to number the citations. The argument `\printbibliography` simply prints the bibliography at that position.

It might (dependent on which editor you use) be necessary to run pdfLaTeX->BibTeX->pdfLaTeX->pdfLaTeX. If you don't see any updates, it might be useful to delete all output files (.aux, .bbl, etc) before recompiling.

Comment: Clickable citations can by the way be created by using the package `hyperref`, for example in the form `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}` to avoid red boxes around the citation.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @Betohaku What you give is a nice explanation of the bibtex workflow with standard latex.  However the questioner is askng about biblatex, so you should extend your answer to cover that.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thank you, it has now been added.

Comment: I am a little busy atm, but I will try to follow all the guidelines and try it again. If it succeeds I will accept.